# Why does code not recognize paths in a system shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, fedora, gnome, gnome-shell

I want to use a shortcut to open up a specific folder in Visual Studio Code in a new window. I am on Fedora with Gnome Shell and have tried the integrated shortcut manager that can be found in the settings. When I define a shortcut with the command `code -n ~/path/to/folder`, Visual Studio opens a new file with the name folder. When I run the same command in the terminal it works as expected, i.e. a new window is opened in the specified folder.

Comment: Does it work if you add a `/` to the end? Does the folder already exist in both cases?

Comment: No, that doesn't help. And I made sure the folder exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out `~` cannot be used in this context, so providing an absolute path fixed the issue.